# Regular Expression with specific special characters triggering Arabic

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression that I use to detect special characters.

As I couldn't figure one to just allow any letters, spaces, `-` and ','. Like `California - USA` `Cairo, Egypt` `London UK`.

The regular expression I'm using:

```
'/[!@#$%^&*<>();{}[\]_؟:\+=~\/\?\.\\"\']+/'
```

There are many backslashes used for escaping special regular expression symbols.

However, it works fine with English like `New York - USA`, but it matches any Arabic words like `القاهرة - مصر`  `محمد`.

```php
$input = "القاهرة - مصر";

if (preg_match('/[!@#$%^&*<>();{}[\]_؟:\+=~\/\?\.\\"\']+/', $input)) {
    echo 'match';
}
```

Why is it matching Arabic letters while it only includes specific characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_match('~^[\p{L}\p{M},\s-]+\z~u', $input)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/STDjwX/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[\p{L}\p{M},\s-]+` - one or more letters (`\p{L}`), diacritics (`\p{M}`), commas, whitespaces (`\s`) and hyphens till
- `\z` - the very end of string.